# Would a linear accelerating object be harder to rotate?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Imagine a cylinder-shaped rocket, rotating around an axis perpendicular to the axis of thrust with constant angular speed of w. The rocket starts thrusting after some time. No air pressure, no gravity. Simplifying the problem would say that the angular momentum and thrust are orthogonal to each other, so they wouldn't interfere. However my intution insists that trying to rotate a rocket accelerating would be harder than rotating an idle rocket. Does the the thrust condition really have nothing to do with the rotation?

[image: conceptual image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the equations of motion

- Net force affects the motion *of the center of mass*

  $$\sum \boldsymbol{F} = m \boldsymbol{a}_{\rm cm} $$
- Net torque *about the center of mass* affects the rotational motion of the body

  $$\sum \boldsymbol{\tau}_{\rm cm} = {\bf I}_{\rm cm} \dot{\boldsymbol{\omega}} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times {\bf I}_{\rm cm} \boldsymbol{\omega} $$

So when the equations of motion are summed at the center of mass, the linear and rotational effects are decoupled.

But in general, the location of an applied force affects the net force *and* the net torque about the center of mass which is why intuitively you feel there is some kind of dependency between the two.

To answer the question of the effect of thrust on rotation, assuming that the thrust line of action goes through the center of mass, then it should not change the net torque and thus the thrust condition does not matter (at least for a well-designed rocket).

The last point I  want to make is that thrust does affect rotation, not because of the laws of physics, but as a design choice for rockets.

Comment: Do you mean by, like, thrust vectoring? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Thrust vectoring is an example of the coupling between linear and rotational motion by design.